# Get content uri from file path in android

Tags: android, image

I know the absolute path of an image (say for eg, /sdcard/cats.jpg).  Is there any way to get the content uri for this file ?

Actually in my code, I download an image and save it at a particular location. In order to set the image in an ImageView instance, currently I open the file using the path, get the bytes and create a bitmap and then set the bitmap in the ImageView instance. This is a very slow process, instead if I could get the content uri then I could very easily use the method    `imageView.setImageUri(uri)`

Comment: Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/img.png");

Comment: +1 to the comment, just Uri.parse("file://" + filePath) should do the trick

Comment: Uri.Parse is depreciated and "to be added"

Comment: @pollaris Uri.parse was added in API 1 and it is not marked for deprecation.

Comment: Uri.parse("something"); is not working on me, I can't find the reason why...

Answer (score 534, accepted):

Try with:

```
ImageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/cats.jpg")));
```

Or with:

```
ImageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(new File("/sdcard/cats.jpg").toString()));
```

Comment: thanks! second method works fine on 1.6, 2.1 and 2.2 but first one only on 2.2

Comment: neither of those methods resolves a file path to a content URI. i understand it solved the immediate problem though.

Comment: in case when have sdcard path but wants content uri @Jon O idea work perfectly : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11603841/336990

Comment: Do not hardcode "/sdcard/"; use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() instead

Comment: you can also load image from Uri file path. Code is as follows imgView.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);

Comment: This is what both the above solutions returns:
1. file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20140312_171146.mp4
2. /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20140312_171146.mp4
But what i was looking for is something different. I need the content:// format URI. The answer from Jinal seems to work perfect

Comment: strictly speaking, `Uri.parse(new File("/sdcard/cats.jpg").toString())` is wrong. `getContentResolver().openOutputStream(Uri.parse(new File("/sdcard/cats.jpg").toString()))` will throw exception "File not found exception: No content provider"

Comment: hey `Uri.fromFile` will not work on android 26+, you should use file provider

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman here the same https://stackoverflow.com/a/27603026/7767664

Comment: I agree with  vuhung3990. Try Uri p; if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                            p = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.android.fileprovider", imgFile);
                        } else {
                            p = Uri.fromFile(imgFile);
                        }

Comment: hey none of this doesn't work with api => 29, only one way to get uri by path that i found is - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53349110/5215604

Answer (score 99):

**UPDATE**

> *Here it is assumed that your media (Image/Video) is already added to content media provider. If not then you will not able to get the
> content URL as exact what you want. Instead there will be file Uri.*

I had same question for my file explorer activity. You should know that the contenturi for file only supports mediastore data like image, audio and video. I am giving you the code for getting image content uri from selecting an image from sdcard. Try this code, maybe it will work for you...

```
public static Uri getImageContentUri(Context context, File imageFile) {
  String filePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
  Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
      MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
      new String[] { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID },
      MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "=? ",
      new String[] { filePath }, null);
  if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
    cursor.close();
    return Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + id);
  } else {
    if (imageFile.exists()) {
      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, filePath);
      return context.getContentResolver().insert(
          MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

**For support android Q**

```
public static Uri getImageContentUri(Context context, File imageFile) {
String filePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media._ID},
        MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "=? ",
        new String[]{filePath}, null);
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
    cursor.close();
    return Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + id);
} else {
    if (imageFile.exists()) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
            Uri picCollection = MediaStore.Images.Media
                    .getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
            ContentValues picDetail = new ContentValues();
            picDetail.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, imageFile.getName());
            picDetail.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");
            picDetail.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH,"DCIM/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            picDetail.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING,1);
            Uri finaluri = resolver.insert(picCollection, picDetail);
            picDetail.clear();
            picDetail.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 0);
            resolver.update(picCollection, picDetail, null, null);
            return finaluri;
        }else {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, filePath);
            return context.getContentResolver().insert(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        }

    } else {
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a method to find the content:// URI of my recorded video file and the above code seems to work perfect on Nexus 4(Android 4.3). It would be nice if you can please explain the code.

Comment: I have tried this to get the Content Uri for a File with the Absolute path "/sdcard/Image Depo/picture.png". It didn't work, so i debuged the code path and found that the Cursor is empty, and when the entry is being added to ContentProvider, its giving null as the Content Uri. Please help.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Also this is the fix for Apps crashing in Android preview N (upcoming API level 24), when trying to take a photo with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE using a file: Uri value for EXTRA_OUTPUT resulting in a FileUriExposedException. Just replace your `putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imageFile))` with `putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getImageContentUri(context, imageFile))`.

Comment: I have the file path - file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.packagename/files/out.mp4, but getting null when I try to get contentUri. I also tried changing `MediaStore.Images.Media` to `MediaStore.Video.Media`, but still no luck.

Comment: This is not working on android Pie api 28. Cursor returns null

Comment: Can you update this method for Android 10 as DATA column is not accessible in Android 10 ?

Comment: This is the best solution after the release of android Q.

Answer (score 18):

The accepted solution is probably the best bet for your purposes, but to actually answer the question in the subject line:

In my app, I have to get the path from URIs and get the URI from paths.  The former:

```
/**
 * Gets the corresponding path to a file from the given content:// URI
 * @param selectedVideoUri The content:// URI to find the file path from
 * @param contentResolver The content resolver to use to perform the query.
 * @return the file path as a string
 */
private String getFilePathFromContentUri(Uri selectedVideoUri,
        ContentResolver contentResolver) {
    String filePath;
    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaColumns.DATA};

    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(selectedVideoUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();
    return filePath;
}
```

The latter (which I do for videos, but can also be used for Audio or Files or other types of stored content by substituting MediaStore.Audio (etc) for MediaStore.Video):

```
/**
 * Gets the MediaStore video ID of a given file on external storage
 * @param filePath The path (on external storage) of the file to resolve the ID of
 * @param contentResolver The content resolver to use to perform the query.
 * @return the video ID as a long
 */
private long getVideoIdFromFilePath(String filePath,
        ContentResolver contentResolver) {


    long videoId;
    Log.d(TAG,"Loading file " + filePath);

            // This returns us content://media/external/videos/media (or something like that)
            // I pass in "external" because that's the MediaStore's name for the external
            // storage on my device (the other possibility is "internal")
    Uri videosUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri("external");

    Log.d(TAG,"videosUri = " + videosUri.toString());

    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns._ID};

    // TODO This will break if we have no matching item in the MediaStore.
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(videosUri, projection, MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA + " LIKE ?", new String[] { filePath }, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
    videoId = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);

    Log.d(TAG,"Video ID is " + videoId);
    cursor.close();
    return videoId;
}
```

Basically, the `DATA` column of `MediaStore` (or whichever sub-section of it you're querying) stores the file path, so you use that info to look it up.

Comment: Not always the case, there are two semi-guaranteed columns returned, and that is `OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME & OpenableColumns.SIZE` if the sending app even follows the "rules". I found that some major apps only returns these two fields and not always the `_data` field. In the case where you don't have the data field which normally contains a direct path to the content, you have to first read the content and write it to a file or into memory and then you have your own path.

Answer (score 16):

// This code works for images on 2.2, not sure if any other media types

```
   //Your file path - Example here is "/sdcard/cats.jpg"
   final String filePathThis = imagePaths.get(position).toString();

   MediaScannerConnectionClient mediaScannerClient = new
   MediaScannerConnectionClient() {
    private MediaScannerConnection msc = null;
    {
        msc = new MediaScannerConnection(getApplicationContext(), this);
        msc.connect();
    }

    public void onMediaScannerConnected(){
        msc.scanFile(filePathThis, null);
    }


    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        //This is where you get your content uri
            Log.d(TAG, uri.toString());
        msc.disconnect();
    }
   };
```

Comment: great, helped me with sharing to Google+, as that app requires a media stream with a content Uri -- absolute path does not work.

Comment: Excellent! I can confirm this works with Audio media types as well.

Answer (score 11):

Easiest and the robust way for creating Content Uri `content://` from a File is to use [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html). Uri provided by FileProvider can be used also providing Uri for sharing files with other apps too. To get File Uri from a absolute path of `File` you can use DocumentFile.fromFile(new File(path, name)), it's added in Api 22, and returns null for versions below.

```
File imagePath = new File(Context.getFilesDir(), "images");
File newFile = new File(imagePath, "default_image.jpg");
Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "com.mydomain.fileprovider", newFile);
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use these two ways based on use

`Uri uri = Uri.parse("String file location");`

or

`Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File("string file location"));`

I have tried both ways and both works.

Answer (score 8):

Its late, but may help someone in future.

To get content URI for a file, you may use the following method:

`FileProvider.getUriForFile(Context context, String authority, File file)`

It returns the content URI.

[Check this out to learn how to setup a `FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider)

Answer (score 4):

Obtaining the File ID without writing any code, just with adb shell CLI commands:

```
adb shell content query --uri "content://media/external/video/media" | grep FILE_NAME | grep -Eo " _id=([0-9]+)," | grep -Eo "[0-9]+"
```

Comment: Google "adb get real path from content uri" and this question is top 1, with your 0-vote answer's content in search result summary. So let me be the first to vote. THANK YOU bro!

Comment: This is cool. But it seem you will get: `Permission Denial: Do not have permission in call getContentProviderExternal() from pid=15660, uid=10113 requires android.permission.ACCESS_CONTENT_PROVIDERS_EXTERNALLY`, unless you're rooted.

Comment: so this does need root access of phone?

Answer (score 2):

Is better to use a validation to support versions pre Android N, example:

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=  Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
     imageUri = Uri.parse(filepath);
  } else{
     imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(filepath));
  }
```

---

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=  Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
     ImageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(new File("/sdcard/cats.jpg").toString()));         
  } else{
     ImageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/cats.jpg")));
  }
```

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/71443/reporte-crash-android-os-fileuriexposedexception-en-android-n

Answer (score 0):

U can try below code snippet

```
    public Uri getUri(ContentResolver cr, String path){
    Uri mediaUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(VOLUME_NAME);
    Cursor ca = cr.query(mediaUri, new String[] { MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID }, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[] {path}, null);
    if (ca != null && ca.moveToFirst()) {
        int id = ca.getInt(ca.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
        ca.close();
        return  MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(VOLUME_NAME,id);
    }
    if(ca != null) {
        ca.close();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What is VOLUME_NAME?

Comment: It is "external" or "internal"