# Show Image View from file path?

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-file

I need to show an image by using the file name only, not from the resource id.

```
ImageView imgView = new ImageView(this);
imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img1);
```

I have the image img1 in the drawable folder. I wish to show that image from the file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 738, accepted):

Labeeb is right about why you need to set image using path if your resources are already laying inside the resource folder ,

This kind of path is needed only when your images are stored in SD-Card .

And **try the below code to set Bitmap images from a file stored inside a SD-Card .**

```
File imgFile = new  File("/sdcard/Images/test_image.jpg");

if(imgFile.exists()){

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);

    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}
```

And include this permission in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Almost: ´decodeFile´ takes a String and not a ´java.io.File´.

Comment: Martin the method being called on the java.io.File getAbsolutePath() is returning the string.

Comment: While this works and its correct, its never recommended to "hit" the disk on the main thread. `BitmapFactory` related methods should be called in a bg thread. Picasso will handle that for you automatically.

Comment: So you almost never want to copy paste this code because you are essentially loading the entire raw image into memory. The image should be resized and loaded into memory in the background. Then the image should be set to the ImageView.

Comment: Assuming the file is resized properly and you have the filepath,  I'd recommend the following method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004713/get-content-uri-from-file-path-in-android.  i.e. `ImageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/cats.jpg")));`

Comment: Geting a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError on low end phones .

Comment: It's important to know that this method has the potential of causing OutOfMemory exceptions!

Answer (score 71):

I think you can use this

```
Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("path of your img1");
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
```

Comment: Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("res\\drawable-hdpi\\img1.png"); I set path like the above But i am not able to show the image

Comment: Ho you cannot use that path of your res here. that can only be used to store image form sd card or other memory. I wondered, why u need to set image using path if your resource is there in resource folder

Answer (score 44):

You can also use:

```
    File imgFile = new  File(“filepath”);
    if(imgFile.exists())
    {
        ImageView myImage = new ImageView(this);
        myImage.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imgFile));

    }
```

This does the bitmap decoding implicit for you.

Answer (score 27):

All the answers are outdated. It is best to use [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for such purposes. It has a lot of features including background image processing.

Did I mention it is super easy to use:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(...)).into(imageView);
```

Comment: And it doesn't require permissions if working with file from gallery or camera.

Comment: Update: `Picasso.get().load(new File(...)).into(imageView);`

Answer (score 24):

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Images/test.jpg";

File imgFile = new File(path);
if(imgFile.exists())
{
   Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
   ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
  imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

From the official site: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagePreview);           
try {
    image.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmap(picFilename));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here the methods:

```
    private int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    private Bitmap decodeSampledBitmap(String pathName,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);
    }

//I added this to have a good approximation of the screen size: 
    private Bitmap decodeSampledBitmap(String pathName) {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;
        return decodeSampledBitmap(pathName, width, height);
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

### How To Show Images From Folder path in Android

### Very First: Make Sure You Have Add Permissions into Mainfest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

### :Make a Class MyGallery

```
public class MyGallery extends Activity {


    private GridView gridView;
    private String _location;

    private String newFolder = "/IslamicGif/";
    private String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    private AdView mAdView;
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> photo = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    public static String[] imageFileList;
    TextView gallerytxt;

    public static ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.mygallery);
        /*if (MenuClass.mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            MenuClass.mInterstitialAd.show();
        }*/

        gallerytxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gallerytxt);
        /*gallerytxt.setTextSize(20);
        int[] color = {Color.YELLOW,Color.WHITE};
        float[] position = {0, 1};
        Shader.TileMode tile_mode0= Shader.TileMode.REPEAT; // or TileMode.REPEAT;
        LinearGradient lin_grad0 = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 200,color,position, tile_mode0);
        Shader shader_gradient0 = lin_grad0;
        gallerytxt.getPaint().setShader(shader_gradient0);*/
        ImageButton btn_back = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
        btn_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MyGallery.this.finish();
            }
        });


        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        new MyGalleryAsy().execute();

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MyGallery.this, ImageDetail.class);
                intent.putExtra("ImgUrl", imageFileList[pos]);

                //Toast.makeText(MyGallery.this,"image detail"+pos,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (ImageDetail.deleted) {
            photo = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
            new MyGalleryAsy().execute();
            ImageDetail.deleted = false;
        }

    }

    public class MyGalleryAsy extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        Bitmap mBitmap;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyGallery.this, "", "Loading ...", true);
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            readImage();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            DisplayMetrics displayMatrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMatrics);
            int screenWidth = displayMatrics.widthPixels / 3;

            if (photo.size() > 0) {
                imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(MyGallery.this, screenWidth);
                gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
            }

        }

    }


    private void readImage() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        try {
            if (isSdPresent()) {
                _location = extStorageDirectory + newFolder;
            } else
                _location = getFilesDir() + newFolder;
            File file1 = new File(_location);

            if (file1.isDirectory()) { // sdCard == true
                imageFileList = file1.list();
                if (imageFileList != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < imageFileList.length; i++) {
                        try {
                            photo.add(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_location + imageFileList[i].trim()));
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    public static boolean isSdPresent() {
        return Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        private int width;
        private int mGalleryItemBackground;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            context = c;

        }

        public ImageAdapter(Context c, int width) {
            context = c;
            this.width = width;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return photo.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.galleryadapter, null);

            RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.galleryLayout);

            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
            layout.addView(imageView, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, width));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            layout.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, width));
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo.get(position));

            return v;

        }

        public void updateItemList(ArrayList<Bitmap> newItemList) {
            photo = newItemList;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }


}
```

### Now create its Xml Class

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gallerytxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="@string/font_fontFamily_medium"
        android:text="My Gallery"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp" />
</RelativeLayout>


<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:visibility="gone"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_id" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"></GridView>
```

## Also Make Adapter galleryadapter.xml ##

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/galleryLayout"
android:padding="2dp">
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

### To see the Image in Detail create a new Class ImageDetail:##

```
 public class ImageDetail extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    public static InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private ImageView mainImageView;
    private LinearLayout menuTop;
    private TableLayout menuBottom;
    private Boolean onOff = true;
    private ImageView delButton, mailButton, shareButton;

    private String imgUrl = null;
    private AdView mAdView;
    TextView titletxt;
    private String newFolder = "/IslamicGif/";
    private String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    public static boolean deleted = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.image_detail);

        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        mainImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainImageView);
        menuTop = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.menuTop);
        menuBottom = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.menuBottom);
        titletxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titletxt);
        titletxt.setTextSize(22);
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstial_id));

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                requestNewInterstitial();

            }
        });
        requestNewInterstitial();
        delButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.delButton);
        mailButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mailButton);
        shareButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.shareButton);

        Bundle exBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (exBundle != null) {
            imgUrl = exBundle.getString("ImgUrl");
        }
        if (isSdPresent()) {
            imgUrl = extStorageDirectory + newFolder + imgUrl;
        } else
            imgUrl = getFilesDir() + newFolder + imgUrl;

        if (imgUrl != null) {
            GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewTarget = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(mainImageView);
            Glide.with(this).load(imgUrl).into(imageViewTarget);

        }


        delButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mailButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        shareButton.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    public static boolean isSdPresent() {
        return Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (arg0.getId()) {
            case R.id.shareButton:
                Image_Link();
                break;
            case R.id.delButton:
                deleted();
                break;
            case R.id.mailButton:
                sendemail();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void sendemail() {

        try {

            File photo = new File(imgUrl);
            Uri imageuri = Uri.fromFile(photo);


            String url = Constant.AppUrl;

            SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
            builder.append("Face Placer App Available here..Play Link");
            int start = builder.length();
            builder.append(url);
            int end = builder.length();

            builder.setSpan(new URLSpan(url), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            Intent emailIntent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            String[] recipients2 = new String[]{"mymail@email.com", "",};
            emailIntent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients2);
            emailIntent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sample mail");
            emailIntent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageuri);
            emailIntent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, builder);
            emailIntent2.setType("text/html");
            emailIntent2.setType("image/JPEG");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent2, "Send mail client :"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    private void Image_Link() {

        try {

            File photo = new File(imgUrl);
            Uri imageuri = Uri.fromFile(photo);


            String url = Constant.AppUrl;

            SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
            builder.append("Face Placer App Available here..Play Link");
            int start = builder.length();
            builder.append(url);
            int end = builder.length();

            builder.setSpan(new URLSpan(url), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            Intent emailIntent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            String[] recipients2 = new String[]{"mymail@email.com", "",};
            emailIntent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients2);
            emailIntent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sample mail");
            emailIntent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageuri);
            emailIntent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, builder);
            emailIntent2.setType("text/html");
            emailIntent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Face Placer App Available here..Play Link " + url);
            emailIntent2.setType("image/JPEG");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent2, "Send mail client :"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    private void deleted() {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ImageDetail.this);
        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.removeoption));
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.deleteimage));
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User clicked OK button
                dialog.cancel();
                File fileDel = new File(imgUrl);
                boolean isCheck1 = fileDel.delete();

                if (isCheck1) {
                    deleted = true;
                    finish();
                    MyGallery.imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User clicked OK button
                dialog.cancel();

            }
        });
        Dialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();


    }


    private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (ni == null) {
            // There are no active networks.
            return false;
        } else
            return true;
    }

    private void requestNewInterstitial() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("SEE_YOUR_LOGCAT_TO_GET_YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
                .build();

        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

}
```

### Create its xml image_detail.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mainImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/adlayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone"></LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/menuTop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/adlayout"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10.0dip"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titletxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Islamic Gifs"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/menuBottom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:padding="10.0dip"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <TableRow>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mailButton"
                android:layout_width="52dp"
                android:layout_height="52dp"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_shareimage"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/shareButton"
                android:layout_width="52dp"
                android:layout_height="52dp"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_shareimage_small"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/delButton"
                android:layout_width="52dp"
                android:layout_height="52dp"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_delete"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/menuTop"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_id"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

### Add your own Drawable to Selector class,and create it res>drawable>selector_shareimage.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/result_bt_mail" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/result_bt_mail" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/result_bt_mail" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/result_bt_mail_s"/>
```

[image]

Dont forget to add in application tag for sdk version 29 and 30 [image: legacy] to add this line

android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: This question is JUST about "Show Image View from file path" !

Comment: The great example that less is more! You overcomplicated your answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
ImageView imgView = new ImageView(this);
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/drawable/" + fileName);
imgView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromStream(is, ""));
```

Answer (score 4):

You may use this to access a specific folder and get particular image

```
 public void Retrieve(String path, String Name)
   {
    File imageFile = new File(path+Name);

    if(imageFile.exists()){

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path+Name);
        myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.savedImage);
        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        Toast.makeText(SaveImage.this, myBitmap.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

And then you can call it by

```
Retrieve(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Aqeel/Images/","Image2.PNG");
Toast.makeText(SaveImage.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
       public static Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
    Bitmap b = null;
    File f = new File(path);
    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o);
        fis.close();

        int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 1024; // maximum dimension limit
        int scale = 1;
        if (o.outHeight > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE || o.outWidth > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
            scale = (int) Math.pow(2, (int) Math.round(Math.log(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE / (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth)) / Math.log(0.5)));
        }

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;

        fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o2);
        fis.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return b;
}

public static Bitmap showBitmapFromFile(String file_path)
{
    try {
        File imgFile = new  File(file_path);
        if(imgFile.exists()){

            Bitmap pic_Bitmap = decodeFile(file_path);
            return pic_Bitmap;

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        MyLog.e("Exception showBitmapFromFile");
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

if you are  using image loading in List view then use Aquery concept .

https://github.com/AshishPsaini/AqueryExample

```
     AQuery  aq= new AQuery((Activity) activity, convertView);
            //load image from file, down sample to target width of 250 pixels .gi 
    File file=new File("//pic/path/here/aaaa.jpg");
    if(aq!=null)
    aq.id(holder.pic_imageview).image(file, 250);
```

Answer (score 3):

onLoadImage Full load

```
private void onLoadImage(final String imagePath) {
    ImageSize targetSize = new ImageSize(imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight()); // result Bitmap will be fit to this size

    //ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(); // Get singleto
    com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader imageLoader = com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getContext()));

    imageLoader.loadImage(imagePath, targetSize, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(final String imageUri, View view) {
            super.onLoadingStarted(imageUri, view);

            progress2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    progress2.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_green_light, android.R.color.holo_orange_light, android.R.color.holo_red_light);

                    // Picasso.with(getContext()).load(imagePath).into(imageView);
                    // Picasso.with(getContext()).load(imagePath) .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE).into(imageView);

                    Glide.with(getContext())
                            .load(imagePath)
                            .asBitmap()
                            .into(imageView);
                }
          });
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            if (view == null) {
                progress2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            // else { 
              Log.e("onLoadImage", "onLoadingComplete");
            //   progress2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            // }
            // setLoagingCompileImage();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
            super.onLoadingFailed(imageUri, view, failReason);
            if (view == null) {
                progress2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            Log.e("onLoadingFailed", imageUri);
            Log.e("onLoadingFailed", failReason.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
            super.onLoadingCancelled(imageUri, view);
            if (view == null) {
                progress2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            Log.e("onLoadImage", "onLoadingCancelled");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Most of the answers are working but no one mentioned that the high resolution image will slow down the app , In my case i used images RecyclerView which was taking 0.9 GB of device memory In Just 30 Images.

> I/Choreographer: Skipped 73 frames!  The application may be doing too
> much work on its main thread.

The solution is Sipmle you can degrade the quality like here : [Reduce resolution of Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35222639/11815154)

But I use Simple way , Glide handles the rest of work

```
fanContext?.let {
            Glide.with(it)
                .load(Uri.fromFile(File(item.filePath)))
                .into(viewHolder.imagePreview)
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void showImage(ImageView img, String absolutePath) {
  
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 8;
    Bitmap bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(absolutePath);
    img.setImageBitmap(bitmapPicture);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can easily do this using bitmap. You can find the code below :**

```
ImageView imageView=findViewById(R.id.imageView);

Bitmap bitMapImage= BitmapFactory.decodeFile("write path of your image");

imageView.setImageBitmap(bitMapImage);
```

Answer (score -6):

```
mageView.setImageResource(R.id.img);
```