# convertion from string to image

Tags: android, android-imageview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show Image View from file path in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181774/show-image-view-from-file-path-in-android)

here image path is stored as string i want convert the string to image and need to view the image in emulator how is this possible? please tell me

thanks

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181774/show-image-view-from-file-path-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Use an [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) and add your string as an resource.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImagePath);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
image.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Assuming `mImagePath` is a string that contains your path and `R.id.image_view` is the ID of an ImageView in your layout.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181774/show-image-view-from-file-path-in-android/4182060#4182060) might help. From that answer:

```
File imgFile = new  File(“/sdcard/Images/test_image.jpg”);
if(imgFile.exists()){
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile);
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
}
```