# saving camera pics in sd card

Tags: android

I am using the following code to take picture, using the device camera. I am new to android. Can anybody please help me and tell me where I should specify the path. I want to save images in a separate folder in sd card. Any help is deeply appreciated.

```
private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 2500;

bcontinue.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
          startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
     }
 });

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST && resultCode==RESULT_OK) 
        {

            try{
                 Byte image1 = (Byte) data.getExtras().get("data");
                     FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("filename.bmp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                 fos.write(image1);
                 fos.close();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){

                    }           
              Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
              ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);               
              imageview.setImageBitmap(image);

              Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Click on the image!";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will start the default camera and have the camera save the image to the specified uri. The key is to put the extra "MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT" along with the desired uri.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Images/" + image_name + ".jpg");
Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, will check it and come back with the comments soon

Comment: Bro I have some more doubt.I want to save pics in a folder called "All" in my sd card. How should I set that path now?

Comment: sry it took me so long to get back.. erm, if I remember correctly if you just change the path you're opening to /All/... you should be fine.. for example:
`File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/All/" + image_name + .jpg);`

Comment: thanks bro, got it right. Now the image is getting saved. But I am getting a force close now after I save the image. Should I make any changes to my previous code, i mean in the onActivityResult part?

Comment: It seems like according to [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html] that if you pass a URI to store the photo in, a bitmap will not be returned as an extra. In other words, when the way you're trying to set the imageview image by getting the image from the extra will not work. Rather, you will have to go to the uri that you saved the image from and get it from there.

Comment: if the image's uri is mImageUri, then you could use this code to set mThumbnail to your image: `mThumbnail.setImageBitmap(ActivityReviewImage.decodeFile(this, mImageUri, 150));
`

Comment: Thanks again bro,can u give me a sample code to retrieve the images from this directory using another activity?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181774/show-image-view-from-file-path-in-android] has some sample code for how to get a Bitmap/set an image view from a file.