# load images using its path in the database in android

Tags: android

Is it possible to load an image from its path saved in the database. The image is actually saved in the sd card (the default gallery).

This is the path of the image saved in the database

```
/mnt/sdcard/download/68107_174917912527848_100000289204785_530969_2619951_n-1.jpg
```

I want to load this image on an image view when an activity starts.

Comment: Dis you try what i suggested in last comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch Image path from database using select query,

then ,

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(<pathOfImage>);
ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: ya. But isn't it necessary to use 
ImageView user=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)

Comment: ya now the way i did it is as you said 

ImageView user;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(loc);
        user=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        user.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: But it is not getting displayed

Comment: I am not getting anything displayed... loc is a string to which I have assigned the value of that path

Comment: yeah it exists.. i have checked

Comment: The reason why I assigned it to a string is coz I have provided an option to change the pic in which i can select pic from gallery and display it.

Comment: thanks but what should i do if i want to change the pic as i mentioned

Comment: hey thats not the thing.. I am saving the location in the db. Then I select the value using select query and I assigned that loc variable with the value that was selected using cursor 

Cursor c1 = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM USER_PROFILE WHERE user_id='1'", null);
String loc=c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("user_picture"));

Comment: yeah... i its working the way u said. But how can I change the image ? I cannot assign a value directly to the loc string coz it will change when i select another picture

Comment: yes i have done that. But I am not getting a way to change the pic. Can please help me on that too.

Comment: Now, using your code just put Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(""+loc);  and let me know what happen.

Comment: sorry to respond late. But i got it....The reason was the position where I had placed the code

Answer (score 1):

Its like reading any other file from sdcard, you can use BitmapFactory to convert File into bitmap and use it in imageview,

Check this,
[Show Image View from file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181774/show-image-view-from-file-path-in-android)