# how to send image from one activity to other?

Tags: android, android-activity, imageview, send

I need send a imageview like i send the string "title", but i can't, how can i send a imageview (R.drawable.image) from mainactivity to secondactivity?

THANKS

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
public void NewActivity(View view){ 
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class); 
intent.putExtra("title", getString(R.string.title));    
startActivity(intent); 
}
```

SECOND ACTIVITY

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) 
{ 

super.onCreate(bundle); 
setContentView(R.layout.pantalla); 
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
if (extras == null) 
{ 
return; 
} 
String title = extras.getString("title"); 

TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.titulo); 

textview.setText(title); 
}
```

Comment: Is the `ImageView` you want to send, or just the image itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution 1:** (for non `drawable` resources)

You can send the path filename as a string. Just like the `"title"` in your example.

*If you have problem with usage of filepath to ImageView.
[Show Image View from file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181774/show-image-view-from-file-path-in-android)*

---

**Solution 2:** (for `drawable` easy & light way)

Send the resource integer value like:

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class); 
intent.putExtra("resourseInt", R.drawable.image);    
startActivity(intent);
```

SECOND ACTIVITY

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) 
{ 

    super.onCreate(bundle); 
    setContentView(R.layout.pantalla); 
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    if (extras == null) 
    { 
        return; 
    } 
    int res = extras.getInt("resourseInt"); 

    ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.something); 

    view.setImageResourse(res); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the path of the picture in putExtra.  Do not send bitmap it may be heavy

Answer (score 3):

Save filepath

```
intent.putExtra("imagePath", filepath);
```

to send the image through intent and use

```
String image_path = getIntent().getStringExtra("imagePath");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_path);
myimageview.setImageDrawable(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Drawables are available throughout all the activities in your application .**

You can access them **directly** instead of sending them from one activity to another.