# Add custom image to Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-imageview, qr-code

What I was trying to do is an app that read QR-CODES (referred to images) and just after the reading, showing a Dialog with the image related to the QR-CODE and the description taken by a database.

Any advice on how to do that?

What I could find on the Internet was just how to create Dialog with custom layout. Nothing more.

Comment: What are you looking for, how to make custom dialog.. is that your question

Comment: you need to display a custom image in custom dialog?

Comment: @Raghunandan yes this is it. You know how to do it?

Comment: Well, if only custom dialog with image is required then [go for this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16354899/2345913). hope. this helps. Please provide clarity of what you desire if not this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you need t o display a Image in a custom dialog

Define dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In your activity on button click display a dialog

```
 Button b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showpopup();        
        }

    });

   public void showpopup()
   {
   Dialog d = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
   d.setContentView( R.layout.dialog);
   d.setTitle("my title");
   ImageView iv = (ImageView) d.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
   iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.afor); 
   // set your image here. I have used a resource from the drawable folder
   d.show();
   }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Raghunandan. You got my problem in a second and now i can do what i wanted! Now i'm trying to get the description from the Database

Comment: Yes sorry it was a missclick. You got it! Thanks so much

Comment: I guess it would have look better if the image was A for android :P

Comment: Can you help me more please? I noticed that doing that, it does just let me select R.drawable.afor . But i have to choose everytime a different image, not always "afor"

Comment: you can once you get the image you can set the bitmap to the iv.setImageBitmap(bm)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181774/show-image-view-from-file-path-in-android. if you have a path you can use the answer in the link. all you need is the image and then you can set the same to imageview

Answer (score 0):

you can use `setContentView()` n just pass ImageView as parameter to it.

Comment: I wanted to add a custom image.

Answer (score 0):

For custom Dialog you have to just create one layout and set that layout in dialog.

e.g

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialog);
```

See this example,[Click Here.](http://dhruvvaishnav.blogspot.in/2013/05/create-custom-dialog.html)