# save image by path and retrieve by sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am capturing image via my application and I successfully stored in sdcard folder which I had created for my application. Now I need to retrieve the stored image in list view. Saving  the images in sqlite is not an efficient way. Can any one direct me in any other way on how to save and retrieve like using path.

Am capturing picture here:

```
private void captureImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

And I have also created the directory in sd card to save my captured images via my application below:

```
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File (
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME
    );

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                    + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;

    if (type ==MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File (mediaStorageDir.getPath()+ File.separator 
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mediaFile;
}
```

Comment: If you want to retrieve it later, store the imagePath in sqlLite.

Comment: @Tejas : i have a feild editext which contain name, address, etc and also imageview. imageview contain onclik listener while clicking imageview its go to camera and capturing the image , captured image displayed in image view. and also  user can enter the value in to edittext field. after entered the value there is button to save .user click tat button means edit text text datas stored in sqlite and succesfully retrived in listview. but ! how can i show that captured image into listview along with my editext data's ?

Comment: When you click SAVE, store the imagepath as well along with edittext data. And when you load list, load image for imageview from SD card using that path.

Comment: I hope you are able to store the imagePath to the database. Are you using custom list?????

Comment: Which one is good way, storing image path or storing the file name ?

Comment: I'd prefer image path.

Comment: could you provide any links ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link will give you how to get the image path and save it in Database[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890818/how-to-store-retrieve-image-path-in-sqlite-db-for-android)

And after retrieving the file path, you'll have to load image from that path.
To load image from file path,this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181774/show-image-view-from-file-path-in-android) will help you.