# Activity runs slow with a couple of ImageView-s

Tags: android, performance, imageview

I have an activity containing 4 images in total. They are all matching the resolution of a 1080x1920 device. When I run the activity with those images, which are loaded directly in my activity via the XML, it runs **tremendously slow** in my Genymotion emulator and **lags** on a real Android device. 


Here is the setup:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
...>
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
...>
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:src="@drawable/shot_header"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

 </LinearLayout>
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            .../>
 </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

The first image is in a CollapsingToolbarlayout. The resolution of the image is **1080x649** PNG.


The content_activity:

This image fills the parent width.It's resolution is **1080x772** PNG.

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:id="@+id/main_image"
    android:layout_below="@+id/shot_error_field"
    android:src="@drawable/forehand_midpng"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
```

The other 2 images are in a *LinearLayout*, their resolution is **500x399**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main_image">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:src="@drawable/forehand_mid_wrong"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </View>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:src="@drawable/forehand_mid_wrong"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

To summarize, I have an activity with 4 ImageViews, populated with properly sized images, which should no problem for a modern Android device. The problem is that this activity is running extremely slow and lagging due to a high memory consumption. 


Am I doing something wrong? How can I further optimize those images? 


I looked into other threads- [out of memory issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object) but none seems to propose a solution to such a problem.

Comment: ImageView generally doesn't like big images.

Comment: Have you try with `android:largeHeap="true"`? This is not recommendable but if nothing works it may be helpfull.

Comment: problem is image resolution.. kindly resize

Comment: If ImageView doesen't like images, how is Facebook app even running?

Comment: @BhaveshRangani how to resize dynamically for every device?

Comment: largeHeap may only hide the problem of memory shortage but will not help with "lags" and "slow"

Comment: @DannyBabbev Are you loading images from URL or from Drawable.?

Comment: @SuhasB Images are loaded from drawable

Comment: did you define different images for different device dp ? (you know like drawable-xhdp/ drawable-mdp)

Comment: Still you use Piscao Library it auto caching

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Problem is `resolution` of the image, if you can `reduce resolution` of the image then work fine, here is some example for reducing `image resolution` and size.

If you pass bitmap width and height then use below function.

```
    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int bitmapWidth,
            int bitmapHeight) {
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight,
                true);
    }
```

if you want bitmap ratio same and reduce bitmap size. then pass your maximum size bitmap. you can use this function

```
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    float bitmapRatio = (float)width / (float) height;
    if (bitmapRatio > 0) {
        width = maxSize;
        height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
    } else {
        height = maxSize;
        width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
    }
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
}
```

or if you are using drawable resources then use this method

```
public Drawable resizeImage(int imageResource) {// R.drawable.large_image
    // Get device dimensions
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    double deviceWidth = display.getWidth();

    BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) this.getResources().getDrawable(
            imageResource);
    double imageHeight = bd.getBitmap().getHeight();
    double imageWidth = bd.getBitmap().getWidth();

    double ratio = deviceWidth / imageWidth;
    int newImageHeight = (int) (imageHeight * ratio);

    Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imageResource);
    Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(this.getResources(),
            getResizedBitmap(bMap, newImageHeight, (int) deviceWidth));

    return drawable;
}

/************************ Resize Bitmap *********************************/
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {

    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();

    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

    // create a matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    // recreate the new Bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height,
            matrix, false);

    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Excellent! The `resizeImage()` method worked perefctly

Comment: Damn, thank you so much for that `resizeImage()` function man! Got my activity with a huge background running super smooth now.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this should not be an issue and these images are not so big to make you phone laggy. Take a look on other stuff you have in the application, it is possible there is some heavy operations (like DB writing/readin, API requests) right in UI thread.

If there is no such operations and you see such problems with the perfomance, try to set these images via some libraries, like Picasso.

Gradle dependency:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
```

And code will look like this:

`Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.my_image).into(toolbar);`

Answer (score 0):

TRY

1. Definitely reduce the size of the images.
2. Cache images if you can.
3. Download the images on a different thread. Store a HashMap would
   make it easy for you

When you get the list of image urls, iterate through them:

```
pictures.put(id,view);
        try{
            FileInputStream in = openFileInput(id);
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, null);
        view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }catch(Exception e){
            new Thread(new PictureGetter(this,mHandler,id)).start();
        }
```

Code to update the image view:

```
if(id!=null){
        ImageView iv = pictures.get(id);
        if(iv!=null){
            try{
                FileInputStream in = openFileInput(id);
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, null);
                iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
```

Comment: The size of my images is low. The largest is **351 KB**

Comment: that is reason. it should be evenless than that for smooth working

Answer (score 0):

Try facebook's fresco library. It can handle large images and one of my projects, reduces memory consumption about 50%.