# Splashscreen in Android app: image is not loading

Tags: android, android-layout, splash-screen

I am a beginner with android. I created, with android studio, a splash screen of a simple Logo (png of 1300x400 px) and when I run it work. I created an apk with the build function (to try on a smartphone) but it does not load the image (white screen for 3 seconds and then the app starts). Is it a phone problem (a simple vodafone VFD 600)?

This is the code

activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_splash_screen.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f1f1f1" >

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textColor="#454545"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="www.codeseasy.com" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

SplashSCreen.java

```
 package com.example.splashscreen;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

@override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@override public void run() {
Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class); startActivity(i);
finish(); } }, 5000);
}}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.splashscreen">

        <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@Mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@String/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@Mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@Style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:theme="@Style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        </application>

        </manifest>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.splashscreen

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
}
```

Good morning, I tried the apk on another smartphone, huawei p10, and it works. At this point the problem must be the smartphone. another question: is it possible to put a video instead of an image? obviously in the video the forward, backward, stop keys must not appear ... thanks.

Comment: Is logo in the correct folder? When you see the logo file on the Android Studio file explorer do you see anything like "drawable-xhdpi"? Or something like that?

Comment: Why do you want to load image? Put it in drawable folder and use it

Comment: Your app works correctly in emulator?

Comment: MohammadMoeinGolchin yes

Comment: Cutiko.   the png file is located in the res / drawable folder with the name logo.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check if your png is big in size or not .Because imageView generally doesn't like big images. 
And if you still want to go-ahead then try changing your image resolution then it work fine . 
Check the re-size method from this post .[Activity runs slow with a couple of ImageView-s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35222406/activity-runs-slow-with-a-couple-of-imageview-s)

Hope its helpful

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I tried the apk on another smartphone, huawei p10, and it works. At this point the problem must be the smartphone.

Comment: You are right .It could be device specific issue but still you can't ignore any specific device , while building your application.