# How to solve image view lagging in scroll view

Tags: java, android, android-studio

All of the image sizes are only below 150kb. I know is the resolution problem, but how can I solve it without changing the resolution? All of the images have different resolutions. The biggest one is 1800*1200 pixels, the smallest is 1109*614 pixels. I have tried the answer find at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35222406/activity-runs-slow-with-a-couple-of-imageview-s). But it does not work.

[This is the output interface.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxj0B.jpg)

This is my source code. I was cutting it to become shorter because the system does not allow me to post it in longer code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="top"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<ScrollView

    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical"
       >

       <FrameLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">



            <ImageView

                android:src="@drawable/back" />

            <TextView


                android:fontFamily="@font/im_fell_dw_pica_sc"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView

                android:src="@drawable/abs3" />


            <TextView

                android:fontFamily="@font/im_fell_dw_pica_sc"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView

                android:src="@drawable/leg" />


            <TextView
              />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView

                android:src="@drawable/chest"
                />


            <TextView
               />

        </FrameLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Are you using any library for displaying the images? like Glide or Picasso? Also, these images are coming from a remote source like URL or locally stored? Please post your code.

Comment: I have updated my XML code, please take a look. All of the pictures are locally stored.

Comment: What  is the resolution of the images in pixels?

Comment: All of the images have different resolutions. The biggest one is 1800*1200 pixels, the smallest is 1109*614 pixels.

Comment: You might try loading these images via a library like Glide instead of directly loading the images as in your case. They internally take care of a lot of memory/paging related stuff which can potentially fix the lag issue.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, I will learn it and try it.