# Displaying from external storage?

Tags: android, imageview, storage

I have an image saved in my Pictures folder, how to display it in a imageview?

like:

```
imageview.setimage("//Pictures//cat.jpg)
```

I know it's not a correct code, but I want to achieve something like this, hope someone can help, thanks!

Comment: It's old, but wouldn't this work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181774/show-image-view-from-file-path-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you first generate a bitmap from file path and then put that bitmap to imageview

```
File image = new File(filePath);
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath(),bmOptions);
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,parent.getWidth(),parent.getHeight(),true);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

**Edit:** Also add this permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set image like this from the sd card **get path** and **create file variable** and **decode file** using **BitmapFactory** set imageview image

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageState()+"/Pictures//cat.jpg";
File f = new File(path);
imageview.setImageBitmap(new BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath()));
```

Answer (score 1):

First you passing wrong file path.

for Correct File path do like this

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath());
```

then create your URL like.

```
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath()) + "/cat.jpg";
```

Then use like this.

```
File image = new File(filePath);
imageView.setImageBitmap(new BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath()));
```

Comment: I'm getting parent.getWidth(),parent.getHeight() cannotresolve symbol for parent.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with combination of the 2 posted codes, thanks for everyone, here's the working code:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath();
    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/picFolder/1.jpg";
    File image = new File(filePath);
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath(),bmOptions);
    image1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```