# Enabling drawable resource image in a application folder

Tags: java, android-studio, drawable, assets

I have an application that capture face image and store it in a folder. How can I manually add the images that I want inside the folder using drawable resource? The folder path is

```
mPath = getFilesDir() + "/faceimages/";
```

So basically how can I make png image in `res/drawable/*.png` available in faceimages folder?

Or is there any other way around I can make my png files available in the folder?

Comment: If I correctly understand, you can't. res/drawable can't be edited at runtime. It is filled only when developing.

Comment: thanks. You have any other idea how can i make the images available in the folder?

Comment: Why are they not available? You can use images as files from the filesystem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181774/show-image-view-from-file-path-in-android