# Can't show bitmap in ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I try show a bitmap from the gallery. this is my URL

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20161103_180603.jpg
```

I know how to get bitmap using `onActivityResult()`, but I don't know how to get  a bitmap

this is my source

```
 final ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20161103_180603.jpg", options);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        });
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display Bitmap Image in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181774/show-image-view-from-file-path)

Comment: Never hard code file path in android

Answer (score 0):

please refer below code

```
 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            //Get our saved file into a bitmap object:
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "DCIM"+ File.separator + "Camera "+File.separator + "IMG_20161103_180603.jpg");
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: i tryed it but bitmap is null

Comment: can you please check whether file exist in that given path or not

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem caused by large image size which couldn't be processed at run time. Solved it using this.

```
// Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
public static Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale = 1;
        while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE &&
                o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE) {
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

where `File` f will be retrieved using https://stackoverflow.com/a/20559418/3758972

just put the size of thumbnail you want (typically the size of your imageview) in `REQUIRED_SIZE` and you are done. It will give you a scaled image which you can set to your `imageview`.

Answer (score 0):

```
decodeFile( "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20161103_180603.jpg
```

Change to:

```
decodeFile( "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20161103_180603.jpg
```