# How to set Image local storage path to ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, custom-lists, android-storage

[image]

My CustomList AdapterCode...

```
private final Activity context;

private List<String> list;

public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, List<String> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_single);

    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);


    if (list != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            File imgFile = new File(list.get(i));

            if (imgFile.exists()) {

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            }
        }
    }

    return rowView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}
```

}

I am receiving a list of imagePath like

d: Array path/storage/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170210_163055.jpg

d: Array path/storage/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170210_163037.jpg

d: Array path/storage/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170217_175804.jpg

d: Array path/storage/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170217_175802.jpg

d: Array path/storage/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170210_163056.jpg

Now I want to show these paths to list view either using a custom adapter or using ArrayAdapter.

Comment: check out here : http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181774/show-image-view-from-file-path

Comment: @JaydeepPatel I an unable to parse it to Image view I am getting this list of path into listview How to show image individual??

Comment: @JaydeepPatel please see the Image Above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you are sending an ArrayList of paths tp your custom adapter. Now in the getView() method of custom adapter, add the following:

```
File imgFile = new  File(myList.get(position));

if(imgFile.exists()){

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);
    //the imageview of your custom list item

    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}
```

Let me know if you need help with custom adapter

**NOTE**: If you have a lot of images, I would suggest you to use library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Do no use a for loop inside getview. GetView is itself called everytime a row is created.

```
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);


if (list != null) {

        File imgFile = new File(list.get(position));

        if (imgFile.exists()) {

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        }
}
return rowView;
```

Comment: It works for me. at least now I am able to see the image but I am getting the last image continuously in listView.

Comment: @Niprup Thanks Now Its Perfect, i was using look to populate that list of collection to list view that was wrong logic can u pls specify why that was wrong concept.

Comment: Every adapter has a getView() method. When the listview needs to populate rows, it calls the getView method. getView method, in your case, is inflating list_single layout into a view, setting textview and imageview and returning the inflated view. Now listview will insert this inflated view as a row. What you were doing was, you were looping inside getView, hence for every row, for loop is iterated and the last path in the list is set as image.

Comment: @NipurIyer need one more help in my case how can I select a single image from listview or from Grid view(In First Tab Same Images are there) and Display that Image to Another Fragment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141862/discussion-between-nirup-iyer-and-kuldeep-singh).