# How to set the image to image view that is downloaded to your application in android local

Tags: android, android-imageview

**I have a image downloaded locally in application**

```
/data/data/com.starboard.stella/files/Stella/FragranceFinder/QuestionImages/option1_woman.png
```

How do I access the image to set for image view?

Answer (score 1):

you can use Picasso for that

Picasso.with(context).load(new File(...)).into(imageView);

refernce: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

Creating a File type using your filepath, creating a Bitmap out of that File and setting the Image bitmap of your ImageView using setImageBitmap is probably the best way to go.

Paresh Mayani gives a great solution with code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4182060/5920187

Answer (score 0):

To load an image

```
File imgFile = new  File(pathToPicture);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToPicture);
```

then

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this:

```
try {
        File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/Stella/FragranceFinder/QuestionImages/", "option1_woman.png");
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        ImageView image =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```