# Android Load image from path to imageView

Tags: android

I am trying to load image from file path in local storage to an imageView.

```
private final String PATH = "file:///storage/emulated/0/Downloads/image.png"
```

As suggested elsewhere in the forum I've tried to load it both using Glide:

```
 Glide.with(this)
            .load(PATH)
            .into(imageView);
```

and Bitmap/BitmapFactory:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    File f = new File(PATH);

    if(f.exists()){

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());

        imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

but I always get the placeholder image.

In the manifest I added the permission WRITE.EXTERNAL.STORAGE and READ.EXTERNAL.STORAGE.

Trying to debug it seems to load the correct path in f variable.

Thanks for help

Edit: I have tried all the suggested solution, but I continue gettin blank screen...

I have also made a brand new app with one imageView only to better test:

```
package com.example.android.pic;


import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


Uri PATH = Uri.fromFile(new File((Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Pictures/agata.png")));




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);


    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);

        }


    }
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic);

    Glide.with(this)
            .load(PATH)
            .into(imageView);

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic);

                Glide.with(this)
                        .load(PATH)
                        .into(imageView);
            } else {
                finish();

            }

        }
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
}
```

please help!
Thanks

Comment: Does converting it to an Uri works? `Uri.parse(PATH)`

Comment: are you testing the application on android 6+?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show Image View from file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181774/show-image-view-from-file-path)

Comment: @Amir_P Yes I am testing on Android 7.0. Do you think that is a permission related problem?

Comment: checkout my answer @akstavrh

Answer (score 1):

You Should use this code

```
final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);

final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

image.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
```

in this code you want imageUri that can use StringPATH:

```
private final StringPATH="/storage/emulated/0/Downloads/image.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file path deceleration is wrong.
Try changing PATH to

```
private final StringPATH="/storage/emulated/0/Downloads/image.png"
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried also with this path, but I have the same problem

Comment: try using this private final StringPATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Downloads/image.png";