# ImageView showing grey square instead of image

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-glide

[image]

I've tried several different ways but the imageview still show only a gray square. I'm testing on API 17.

Below are the options I've tried unsuccessfully:

> - Configured the ImageView in XML to:
> - fixed width and height; width and height to wrap_content; width to match_parent and height to wrap_content
> - android: scaleType to "fitXY" and "centerCrop"
> - android: adjustViewBounds to true | false;

Image loading methods tried:

```
binding.captcha.setImageBitmap (BitmapFactory.decodeFile (imgFile2.getAbsolutePath ()));
```

Also tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35830800/1764042

Tried Glide:

```
    Glide.with(this)
    .load (Uri.fromFile (imgFile2))
    .skipMemoryCache (true)
    .diskCacheStrategy (DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
    .override (150, 150)
    .centerCrop ()
    .into (binding.captcha);
```

The option below is the only that displays the image (in background), however I would like to know what could be happening to prevent me from displaying the image using default methods ...

```
    Drawable drawableImage = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile2.getAbsolutePath()));
    binding.captcha.setBackgroundDrawable(drawableImage);
```

- Notes:
- imgFile2 is not empty, it is loaded from SD Card.
- imgFile2 is showing if I use it as background so the problem is not with the file.
- The problem is not simply solved with a lib, I'm already trying Glide... But if you Know what I need to do to make it work with glide...
- The imageView is inside a fragment, if it matters.

Current xml:

```
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/captcha"/>
```

Comment: can you post the output image.

Comment: @Ankur_009 done...

Answer (score 5):

For those who are still facing this issue, for me this is caused because of **`android:tint`** property of `ImageView` to which I was setting image into using Glide.

I was displaying a dummy placeholder image with `android:tint` as a shade of grey while the actual image loads from url. And that tint was causing the problem.

So try removing the `android:tint` property alltogether or set the tint to null programmatically after loading the image using **`imageView.setImageTintList(null)`**

Hope it helps