# Get image file path inside src/main/logo

Tags: android

I am trying to organize about 50 images in the "logo" folder, not in "drawable", but I don't know how to get the base path of the folder.

I tried:

```
String path = "src/main/logo/ataturk.png";
File imgFile = new File(path);
if (imgFile.exists()) {
    ImageView imgLogo = myView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_logo);
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    imgLogo.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
}
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Why not in drawable, raw or assets folder?

Comment: this helps for problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181774/show-image-view-from-file-path

Comment: just to organize files 
drawable file has about 20 files

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access file under a package folder. So put them under assets folder like; /src/main/assets/logo/SUB_DIR/FILENAME.png

Then you can access them `getContext().getResources().getAssets().open('logo/SUB_DIR/FILENAME.png')`

To check if file exists on asset folder use the following code;

```
private boolean fileExists(String folder, String fileName) {

    try {
        String[] files = getResources().getAssets().list(folder);

        for(String file : files) {
            if(file.equals(fileName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Call that method as follows

```
img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgSDCard);
if(fileExists("logo/sub", "sd_card_enable.png")) {
        // asset folder has file
        try {
            img.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open("logo/sub/sd_card_enable.png"), "sd_card_enable.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Copy your files into the assets folder like following picture; 
(logo is a DIR, and sub is a DIR inside logo)

[image]

Comment: not working with me ,
i moved them to drawable folder 

String path = "android.resource://" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "/drawable/img.png";


        File imgFile = new File(path);
        if (imgFile.exists()) {
            ImageView imgLogo = myView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_logo);
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

            imgLogo.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        }

but it look like file not exist

Comment: What you trying to do? You dont need to check files in drawable exists or not. If id is there, means file is there. Android wont create ids for files that does not exists. 

If you can express what you actually trying to achieve might be able to help!

Comment: I have update the answer, please have a look, but still my question is what is your end goal? Just curious