# Loading image selected from internal storage using Uri not working

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview

I tried to select an image from internal storage and load that using imageview. It selects the image but not displaying it.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my layout

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;


   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 100;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openImageChooser();
            }
        });
    }

    /* Choose an image from Gallery */
    void openImageChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                // Get the url from data
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                if (null != selectedImageUri) {
                    // Get the path from the Uri

                    imageView.setImageURI(null);
                    imageView.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this code, after selecting the image it is not displaying it.
My permissions are

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

I figured out that imageview is working by displaying mipmap

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
```

this displays the location of image file(working)

```
   String s = selectedImageUri.toString();
  Toast.makeText(this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: What the result of the uri.toString() ? if it starts with file:// or content:// you need to call ContentProvider.openInputStream

Comment: It gave content://

Comment: Which one should I pass for creating file object?

Comment: The image is probably too big to be displayed. Try with a smaller image.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there!

- You have successfully chosen the image from the filesystem,
- You have verified (by outputting the filename) that you got the correct path to the image.

What you're missing is the way to correctly set the image resource in the `ImageView` from a path. Try this solution: [Show Image View from file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181774/show-image-view-from-file-path)

Use the below code to set Bitmap images from a file stored inside a SD-Card.

```
File imgFile = new  File("/sdcard/Images/test_image.jpg");

if(imgFile.exists()){

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);

    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}
```