# unable to setImage from storage using path/Uri

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to set an ImageButton image using that images file path like so.

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED & ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        ImgButton.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imagePath));

    }
    else
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_CODE);

    }
```

This isnt displaying the image and im not sure why? any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Does it enter the else block? what is image Path? what is the result of Uri.parse(imagePath)?
Debugging might help answer some of these questions.

Comment: The code runs without errors. It has permissions so it enters the if block. imagePath in this case is equal to "/storage/emulated/0/Download/download.jpeg"

Comment: On Android Q. ? What is the size of the jpg file? And its resolution,,?

Comment: Yeah its android Q, as for the size, im not sure how to find that out? would its size and resolution have an effect?

Comment: here's the link that will workif you have the path of file
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4182060/8927208