# Android/Java: How to add icon in my bottom bar dynamically

Tags: java, android, icons, android-navigation-bar

I would like to add icons in my bottom bar dynamically by taking it in a file path with a folder containing all the icons images (to avoid compiling the app each time). I found this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181774/show-image-view-from-file-path) but I don't really understand how to adapt it...

```
   @Override
    public void run() {
        Menu menu = bottomNavigation.getMenu();
        if (menu.size() == 0) {
            MenuMap = new ArrayMap<String, Integer>();
            for (int i = 0; i < myitems_detail.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = myitems_detail.getJSONObject(i);
                    if (obj.getString("ICONE") != null) {
                        int imgID = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(obj.getString("ICONE"), "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
                        MenuItem myItem = menu.add(0, obj.getInt("PAGE_ORDER"), 0, obj.getString("MENU_NAME"))
                                .setIcon(imgID);

                        MenuMap.put(obj.getString("MENU_NAME"), obj.getInt("id"));

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I Think This Works For You
But This Case You Have To Enter Full Path Of File Also Use Any Web Url Of It

```
 Uri filePath = null;
```

Pass Here Url
Or

```
 filePath = Uri.parse("String file location or url");

        Bitmap myBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
        myMenuItem.setIcon(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), myBitmap));
```