# Is it possible to get the resolution of a video in Android?

Tags: android, video, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm looking for a way to get the resolution of any given video in Android. It doesn't have to work with other formats than the ones supported in Android, but it'd be great if it did. If you're unsure of the supported formats in Android, please refer to this page:

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

I think it's possible to do what I want using the `MediaPlayer` class, but that seems incredibly stupid and inefficient. Also, I'd like a way that's *relatively* fast.

I'm targeting Android 3.0+, if that makes any difference. Honeycomb also supports .mkv files, although it's not officially supported until Android 4.0.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use the [MediaMetadataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) to retrieve resolution information about a video file. You'd use the [extractMetadata()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#extractMetadata%28int%29) method and using the `METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT` and `METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH` constants. So you'd do something like this:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
metaRetriever.setDataSource(/* file descriptor or file path goes here */);
String height = metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT);
String width = metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH);
```

Comment: That seems absolutely brilliant! Can't believe I've never heard of that class before. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Is there any easy way for Pre-Honeycomb?

Comment: MediaMetadataRetriever requires API level 14

Comment: You're wrong. MediaMetadataRetriever as added in API 10. If you want to retrieve metadata prior to API 10 you can use FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.

Comment: does it return in String type? int would be better

Answer (score 7):

Trick for API 10+:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mRetriever.setDataSource("video_file_path");
Bitmap frame = mRetriever.getFrameAtTime();

int width = frame.getWidth();
int height = frame.getHeight();
```

We are simple taking a random frame from our video and detecting its width and height.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Video Content URI then you can also use content provider query

Like

```
    Cursor mediaCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                        videoContentURI,
                        {MediaStore.Video.Media.RESOLUTION}, null, null, null);
        if (mediaCursor != null) {
                    if (mediaCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        //The resolution of the video file, formatted as "XxY"
        String resolution=mediaCursor.getString(mediaCursor
                                  .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.RESOLUTION));
    }
}
```

[You can check following post to get ContentURI from video Physical Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004713/get-content-uri-from-file-path-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

### Kotlin Extension Solution

Here is the way to fetch media file dimensions in Kotlin

```
val (width, height) = myFile.getMediaDimensions(context)

fun File.getMediaDimensions(context: Context): Pair<Int, Int>? {
    if (!exists()) return null
    val retriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
    retriever.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse(absolutePath))

    val width = retriever.extractMetadata(METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH).toIntOrNull() ?: return null
    val height = retriever.extractMetadata(METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT).toIntOrNull() ?: return null

    retriever.release()
    return Pair(width, height)
}
```

If you want to make it safer (Uri.parse could throw exception), use this combination. The others are generally just useful as well :)

```
fun String?.asUri(): Uri? {
    try {
        return Uri.parse(this)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
    }
    return null
}

val File.uri get() = absolutePath.asUri()

fun File.getMediaDimensions(context: Context): Pair<Int, Int>? {
    if (!exists()) return 0
    val retriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
    retriever.setDataSource(context, uri)

    val width = retriever.extractMetadata(METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH).toIntOrNull() ?: return null
    val height = retriever.extractMetadata(METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT).toIntOrNull() ?: return null

    retriever.release()
    return Pair(width, height)
}
```

Not necessary here, but generally helpful additional Uri extensions

```
val Uri?.exists get() = if (this == null) false else asFile().exists()

fun Uri.asFile(): File = File(toString())
```