# how to get stats/properties of video?

Tags: android, video

i need to retreive properties  of video like resolution(height/width) ,file format ,bitrate .. etc ..i used MediaMetadataRetriever to get some properties .Is there any other way of getting those properties.

Answer (score 0):

I seek for the same information and i found that the best solution is use MediaMetadataRetriever

[Retrieve the width and Height of a video in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8001020/628447)

I use this solution and the result are perfect, efficient and precise.