# Android: Play audio from internal memory

Tags: android

I am going to be downloading audio files to the device's internal memory. At a later time I would like to play this audio with a MediaPlayer. In the "Media Playback" guide on the developer site it mentioned using a "URI". Is there any way I could just use the filename of the file in the internal memory? How can I play saved audio?

Answer (score 0):

To get the URI from a file path [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004713/get-content-uri-from-file-path-in-android) may help:

it looks like

```
Uri.parse(new File("/sdcard/cats.jpg").toString()) should do the trick.
```