# Convert real path format to Uri in android

Tags: android, android-intent

for example

real path is mnt/sdcard/image_1.jpg
      Uri path  is content://media/external/images/media/140 like this

```
  Uri photoUri =Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media/140");
                                            Log.d("selectedphoto",""+photoUri);
               selectedImagePath = getPath(photoUri);

     public String getPath(Uri uri) {
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();



    return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

In above code I convert Uri to real path but dnt know how to convert real path to Uri

Comment: it help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/11603841/336990

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/cats.jpg"));
```

Comment: take picture using camera to store sdcard folder like mnt/sdcard/image.jpg i need to upload that picture into facebook using hackbook..gallery images are uploaded but camera images are not working.........

Comment: i have real path if it possible to convert the Uri path..have any idea please help me.....thanks

Comment: Works on samsung tab e

Answer (score 0):

This will get the file path from the MediaProvider, DownloadsProvider, and ExternalStorageProvider, while falling back to the unofficial ContentProvider method you mention.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27271131/3758898

Comment: this answer is opposite