# Image path from URI

Tags: android

**I am trying to get an Image file from the gallery:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
        GET_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY);
```

The message "Selecture Picture" is not shown as a Toast.

**And in onActivityResult();**

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData(); //log shows proper URI
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImageUri,
        projection, null, null, null);
int column_index = cursor
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
cursor.moveToFirst();
String selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
```

`cursor.getString(column_index)` **returns Null**.

I am testing it on Nexus 4.

**EDIT:**

Looks like this is a problem with Android 4.4, I have see other apps failing too.

[Convert content:// URI to actual path in Android 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985286/convert-content-uri-to-actual-path-in-android-4-4)

Comment: Possible better solid answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789276/android-get-real-path-by-uri-getpath

Answer (score 8):

Use this :

```
String selectedImagePath = null;
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(
    selectedImageUri, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor == null) { 
    selectedImagePath = selectedImageUri.getPath();
} else {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
    selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(idx);
}
```

Comment: ive got cursor null exception while using nexus and moto g.

Comment: I am getting `Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 6 columns.` error.