# How to get Image Size from PhotoPicker Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Here is my On Click Listener:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
  intent.setType("image/jpeg");
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
  startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PHOTO_PICKER_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

here is my OnActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if (requestCode == PHOTO_PICKER_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
     Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
     File imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri));
     long length = imageFile.length();
     length = length / 1024;
     Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: ImageSize " + length +" Kb");
  }
}
```

ImageSize always returns 0 (zero).

Answer (score 0):

You probably missing the permission in the manifest. You need to add the following permission in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Or, if you're targetting Android 6.0 (API level 23) and above, you need to [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

And please check your `getRealPathFromURI()` method. I've testing with this following code and it's work:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
  String res = null;
  String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
  Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, "", null, "");
  if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    res = cursor.getString(column_index);
  }
  cursor.close();
  return res;
}
```

Or use the code from [Convert content:// URI to actual path in Android 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985286/convert-content-uri-to-actual-path-in-android-4-4/27271131#27271131)

Comment: thank you, silly me i didnot include `getRealPathFromURI()` , but thanks, let me try it out