# How can I open a chosen file by it's URI android

Tags: android

In my app I need to open a file which I choose by Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 1);
```

it's a .docx file and to parse it I need to open a FileInputStream, but I can't get a proper path from URI I get

Logs

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3Adata.docx
content:/com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3Adata.docx (No such file or directory)
```

I tried a few methods, but they didn't help me.
So how I can do it?

Thanks for advance

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19985374/1048340
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5657557/1048340

Comment: If an `InputStream` will suffice, use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`. If you need a file, make a local copy of the content, as is outlined in the duplicate question.