# Can I get the file path of a file I created from the Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT?

Tags: android

If I'm not mistaken, it returns a content scheme URI except for Documents instead of MediaStore entries.

Basically, how do I convert that into a file path, or at least a MediaStore entry?

Comment: As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19985374) you need to use ContentResolver for this

Comment: I am not certain what you mean by "a MediaStore entry". It is up to the document provider to get the content indexed by the `MediaStore`, if that is appropriate for that document provider. The content might not be stored in an indexable location, such as on the Internet in a cloud storage provider.