# How to upload image taken from camera in android into MYSQL database

Tags: php, android, mysql

**How to upload these images taken from camera into MySQL**

I can take multiple images and These images shown in image view but i couldn't find a way       to upload them in to MySQL database. below is my code.

**This is the solution class**

```
    public class solution extends Activity {
    static int count=1;
    ImageView iv;
    ImageView iv2;
    ImageView iv3;
    ImageView iv4;
    ImageView iv5;

@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.solution);

    iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
    iv2=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);
    iv3=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image3);
    iv4=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image4);
    iv5=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image5);

    Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.click);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }
    });
}
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  Bitmap bm=(Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
  if(count==1){

 iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
  }
  if(count==2){
      iv2.setImageBitmap(bm);  
  }
  if(count==3){
      iv3.setImageBitmap(bm);  
  }
  if(count==4){
      iv4.setImageBitmap(bm);  
  }
  if(count==5){
      iv5.setImageBitmap(bm);  
  }
  count++;
}
}
```

Comment: You need some kind of server side api to accept data from android and enter it into database.

Comment: There's no indication as to what you've already done in PHP. You can send binary data to a PHP endpoint and then store it that way.

Comment: Go through this article, http://www.phpriot.com/articles/storing-images-in-mysql You can store image directly to mysql

Answer (score 0):

You have bitmap object that you can save as blob data in to ur database, using contentresolver interface [store image as blob in db only if you have small size of images] http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

If your images are large size you can save them on sdcard then create URI and save this uri to db [Get content uri from file path in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004713/get-content-uri-from-file-path-in-android)

Comment: I want to save the image path in MYSQL DB.

Comment: ye I missed that, as android using Sqlite for database. So this is obivious that you want to upload image on remote location having MYSQL as DB, so you need to have some server api, through you upload your data from android to remote location. [as already @HERO mentioned same]