# Convert a file path to Uri in Android

Tags: android, string, uri

I have an app where I capture a video using the camera. I can get the video's file path, but I need it as a Uri.

The file path I'm getting:

```
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20141219_133139.mp4
```

What I need is like this:

```
content//media/external/video/media/18576.
```

This is my code.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // if the result is capturing Image

         if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // video successfully recorded
                // preview the recorded video
                // selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                // Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                previewVideo();

                tv1.setText(String.valueOf((fileUri.getPath())));
                String bedroom=String.valueOf((fileUri.getPath()));
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.putExtra(bhk1.BEDROOM2, bedroom);
                setResult(RESULT_OK,i); 
                btnRecordVideo.setText("ReTake Video");

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled recording
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled video recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to record video
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }
```

I need a Uri from the String variable `bedroom`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get content uri from file path in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004713/get-content-uri-from-file-path-in-android)

Comment: `// Uri selectedImage = data.getData();`. Well .. isn't that your uri?

Comment: `fileUri.getPath()`. What is filePath? You should have told/shown!

Comment: `I am getting the path is /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20141219_133139.mp4`. Where? We have to guess?

Comment: after i record the video the storage path path is /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20141219_133139.mp4.i need to get like this content//media/external/video/media/18576

Comment: Please react on my comments instead of repeating your question. I understood your question already.

Comment: I want to upload the video to youtube for that the path string is not working,so that i need the video file uri like this content//media/external/video/media/18576

Comment: Hi vinod...did you solve this? i need image uri to upload it to server.

Answer (score 321, accepted):

Please try the following code

```
Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/sample.jpg"))
```

Comment: could be helpful to take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed

Comment: You can use `file.toUri()` for Kotlin

Comment: @grrigore I think you meant toURI() which belongs to java.net package.

Comment: @KMC https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/net/package-summary this is the one I'm talking about

Answer (score 43):

Normal answer for this question if you really want to get something like `content//media/external/video/media/18576` (e.g. for your video mp4 absolute path) and not just `file///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20141219_133139.mp4`:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
          new String[] { file.getAbsolutePath() }, null,
          new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
      public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
          Log.i("onScanCompleted", uri.getPath());
      }
 });
```

Accepted answer is wrong (cause it will not return `content//media/external/video/media/*`)

`Uri.fromFile(file).toString()` only returns something like `file///storage/emulated/0/*` which is a simple absolute path of a file on the sdcard but with `file//` prefix (scheme)

You can also get `content` uri using `MediaStore` database of Android

**TEST** (what returns `Uri.fromFile` and what returns `MediaScannerConnection`):

```
File videoFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/video.mp4");

Log.i(TAG, Uri.fromFile(videoFile).toString());

MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { videoFile.getAbsolutePath() }, null,
        (path, uri) -> Log.i(TAG, uri.toString()));
```

Output:

> I/Test: file:///storage/emulated/0/video.mp4
>
> I/Test: content://media/external/video/media/268927

Comment: whats the difference between `content//` and `file///` , I ask because both works in my case

Comment: please provide a function that gets path and returns uri.

Comment: @aryanknp read about MediaStore

Comment: This answer is the only working answer. Above accepted answer doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to Get Uri path from String File path .this code will be worked also in androidQ.

```
String outputFile = context.getExternalFilesDir("DirName") + "/fileName.extension";

            File file = new File(outputFile);
            Log.e("OutPutFile",outputFile);
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Activity.this,
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",file);
```

declare provider in application Tag manifest

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

under res -> xml ->provider_paths.xml

```
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Answer (score -1):

Below code works fine before 18 API :-

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {

        // can post image
        String [] proj={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery( contentUri,
                        proj, // Which columns to return
                        null,       // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
                        null,       // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
                        null); // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

below code use on kitkat :-

```
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
 * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context The context.
 * @param uri The Uri to query.
 * @param selection (Optional) Filter used in the query.
 * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
 * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
 */
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}


/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

see below link for more info:-

https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java