# Unable to find sound files URI for Media Player

Tags: java, android, uri, media-player

I want to play sound files when user click on certain text. I have sound files list in my **database** and the sound files are **downloading** successfully in my app. I am trying to play these files using `MediaPlayer`. The issue is I **cannot find the URI required to play `MediaPlayer`**. Thus resulting in null media-player object. I have tried nearly all the solutions listed on internet but non solved my issue. The **path** of sound file while downloading from database is

> "/data/user/0/mypackage/files/Sound/diabetes_ur_sound_1_1_1_1.0.0.0.mp3".

Screenshot of one of the method that I used is attached with the debugger output.

Code:
[image: Code]

Debugger Output:
[image: Debugging Output]

Comment: Can you show the structure of your project?

Comment: Try using `setDataSource(filePath);` method of `MediaPlayer`

Comment: a sample file path would be `/storage/sdcard0/Recordings/RECORDING_20180207_124312.m4a`

Comment: @AbuYousuf I have already tried this. Is there any issue with my URI?

Comment: i think the problem is the file path . if filePath is correct then it will work. You can just use your download file path.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/27603026/1292557 to make `URI` from file path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in **downloading** sound files. Therefore the MediaPlayer object results in null.

Now I am downloading the sound with help of static files and using the file path in MediaPlayer. ***Problem Solved***

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setDataSource(Context context, Uri uri)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri)) method. If your path is correct you can pass it as a parameter.

Example:

```
try {
        mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri1);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (SecurityException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Take a look on this [tutorial](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-mediaplayer-example-play-from-uri/)

### Edit

First of all try if it's working hardcoded and then try to get the path dynamically.

Try this with your path

```
mp.setDataSrouce(MainActivity.this, Uri.parse("/data/user/0/mypackage/files/Sound/diabetes_ur_sound_1_1_1_1.0.0.0.mp3"));
```

Comment: Giving me this exception-> java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1

Comment: Do you have this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` in manifest.xml?, when is giving you the error? Is playing music at least?

Comment: Yes.. Its added.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your file is exist in

> getFilesDir().getPath()+"/Sound/"

directory. I think your file is missing in that directory. If your file is exist in that directory then it should work. `MediaPlayer` `null` pointer exception may occur if file is not found. Try checking your file exist before creating `MediaPlayer`. 
If that doesn't work create file in other directory like

> getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)

Comment: Thanks Abu Yousuf. Do you know how to download sound files from api to android app? Because i think there is issue in downloading files that is why it is returning null media player object.

Comment: Use Android System DownloadManager https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html . Check this https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/networking/android-download-manager-tutorial-download-file-using-download-manager-internet/ tutorial

Comment: Thanks. I am on it.

Comment: I downloaded(using some website URL) the sound file in android and successfully played it. Now I am looking for the Web Api method which gives me the URL(in Asp .Net Core). Can you help?

Comment: happy to hear that you successfully played files. "Web Api method which gives me the URL" would you explain it ?

Comment: Successfully Implemented. Thanks Alot for help :D