# Get correct File uri from file path in sdcard when using in Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, image, video, universal-image-loader

Currently, I use the `[Universal Image Loader]` library to load some files from the sd card.
I want to get the following URI from a file path: 
`file:///mnt/sdcard/image.png`

I already tried this way to get file URI: 
`Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(mAlFileList.get(i));`

But the `file URI` already modified to 
`file:///mnt/sdcard/%5B40k%5D/20141014_232337.jpg`

When I use a special character in the folder name, is : `[40k]` - this is the name of this one `%5B40k%5D`.

What I want is get this file URI: `file:///mnt/sdcard/[40k]/20141014_232337.jpg`
But yet I don't know how to get the correct thing.

Please help me out.

P.S.:

- It also apply for a case in that the folder name also includes a space character, like this: `My Folder` (it was changed to %20, but it is not what I want)
- Actually, If I don't use any special character, the library can load the files correctly.

The accepted URI from library:

```
"http :// site.com/image.png" // from Web
"file:///mnt/sdcard/image.png" // from SD card
"file:///mnt/sdcard/video.mp4" // from SD card (video thumbnail)
"content://media/external/images/media/13" // from content provider
"content://media/external/video/media/13" // from content provider (video thumbnail)
"assets://image.png" // from assets
"drawable://" + R.drawable.img // from drawables (non-9patch images)
```

- Code load media files :

  ```
              imageLoader.displayImage(
              Uri.fromFile(new java.io.File(FILE_PATH)).toString()
              ,
              markableImageView, mDio,
              new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                      if (loadedImage != null & view != null) {
                          ((ImageView) view).setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                                  loadedImage,
                                  mContext.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.width_file_view),
                                  mContext.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.height_file_view),
                                  false));
                      }
                  }
              }, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onProgressUpdate(
                          String imageUri, View view, int current, int total) {
                  }
              });
  ```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004713/get-content-uri-from-file-path-in-android#3005936) out.

Comment: @Exception : That way will not work if used `special character in folder name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to get this `file:///mnt/sdcard/[40k]/20141014_232337.jpg`.

So I should try the other way is get `Content Uri`, like `content://media/external/images/media/24415`, not `File Uri` as example in above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/yourImageName.jpg"));
```

Comment: @Neah Ahlucalia : That way will not work if used `special character in folder name`.

Comment: Need find out the other way. Your case also need support the case I mentioned. Please work professional.