# The URI format got from Uri.fromFile(file) is different from the common URI format?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to retrieve the Uri of a file. The file is stored inside:

```
/storage/emulated/0/AppName/FileName.png
```

If I used Uri.fromFile(file), what I got was

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/AppName/FileName.jpg
```

What I wanted is something of this format:

```
content://media/external/images/media/51128?
```

Why doesn't Uri.fromFile(file) gives me this? And how can I get this?

Comment: "Why doesn't Uri.fromFile(file) gives me this?" -- because what you want, for some reason, is a `Uri` from the `MediaStore` `ContentProvider`. "And how can I get this?" -- query the `MediaStore` `ContentProvider`. Whether or not you will find your specific file in there is another matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Uri.fromFile()` gives a file URI, not a content URI, which is what you want.

As to how you can get this, I'd suggest you see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11603841/5512090) since it covers conversion both from and to content URI.

The relevant code, modified slightly to match your media type (image):

```
/**
 * Gets the MediaStore video ID of a given file on external storage
 * @param filePath The path (on external storage) of the file to resolve the ID of
 * @param contentResolver The content resolver to use to perform the query.
 * @return the video ID as a long
 */
private long getImageIdFromFilePath(String filePath,
    ContentResolver contentResolver) {


    long imageId;
    Log.d(TAG,"Loading file " + filePath);

            // This returns us content://media/external/images/media (or something like that)
            // I pass in "external" because that's the MediaStore's name for the external
            // storage on my device (the other possibility is "internal")

    Uri imagesUri = MediaStore.Images.getContentUri("external");

    Log.d(TAG,"imagesUri = " + imagessUri.toString());

    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID};

    // TODO This will break if we have no matching item in the MediaStore.
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(imagesUri, projection, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA + " LIKE ?", new String[] { filePath }, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
    imageId = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);

    Log.d(TAG,"Image ID is " + imageId);
    cursor.close();
    return imageId;
}
```

Comment: When do u need a file URI and when do u need a content URI? Why is there two types of URI?