# Setting an image in CardView using URL

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-bitmap, malformedurlexception

I am creating a `CardView`. I have created the `Adapter` and it is working perfectly. When I initialise the `Bitmap` for my `ImageView` within the `CardView`, I get a red line and an error message under this line:

```
viewHolder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(list.get(position).thumbnail).openConnection().getInputStream()));
```

The message I am receiving is this:

> error: unreported exception MalformedURLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

I have searched through other posts with the same error but their resolutions don't solve my problem. I have tried putting that line within a `try` and `catch` clause like so:

```
try {
   viewHolder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(list.get(position).thumbnail).openConnection().getInputStream()));
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get the same error. The statement `list.get(position).thumbnail` is of type `String`. Why am I getting this error? How do I solve the issue?

Comment: I think you should use third-party for loading image. Ex : Glide, Picasso...

Comment: Can you show logcat URLs get from list ?

Comment: The URL's I get are from images from the Gallery. They have funny URLs and looked like this: `/external/images/media/3666`.

Comment: This is URI not URL. If you want load it, plz read anwser [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3005936/3832212)

Comment: I have read it. I'm not getting any errors but the image is still not appearing. Is it because I have no file extension?

Comment: Right, try again with extension.

Comment: That's the problem. I have an `Intent` in another activity that selects an image from the gallery. The `Uri` that the `Intent` returns doesn't contain a file extension. My `viewHolder` uses that `Uri` to display it in the `ImageView`. Do I need to find the path of that image instead rather that `Uri`?

Comment: Now, you want show image or... ??. If Intent return doesn't contain a file extension, you can handle with String path (concat(.file extension)).
Use Intent view with Gallary [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5384265/3832212)

Comment: @Iris Louis Yes! Thank you very much! It works perfectly!

Comment: You're Wellcome @@~. Can you vote answer for me ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is URI not URL. If you want load it, plz read answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004713/get-content-uri-from-file-path-in-android/3005936#3005936).

Or use Intent view with Gallary [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383797/open-an-image-using-uri-in-androids-default-gallery-image-viwer/5384265#5384265)

Comment: Once again, thank you very much! Your help was greatly appreciated!